# Cordova build erases all app files

Tags: android, cordova

I have some problem with building an app with cordova. This is my first experience with that software.

I have an existing Android HTML/JS app. I want to do some changes to it, re-build and test it in emulator. 
App's files are located in platforms/android/asset/www, I can see them, edit them etc.
Now, after doing the changes, I do a "cordova emulate". I see it builds my app, the emulator starts and… it shows me a Hello World app. 
All app's files from asset/www disappeared, and are replaced with "blank", hello world files , like I would just create a new app.
Why is this happening? How to prevent it?

My current cordova version is 4.3.0. The application was probably made and last edited on some older version (few months ago).

Found a similar problem here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516233/cordova-build-has-erased-my-files-can-they-be-found) but there's no solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of working on the platforms/android/asset/www you have to work on the root www folder, when you run the app the files will be copied to platforms/android/asset/www